# Launching ubuntu from windows

Tags: dual-boot

I need ubuntu for several things but I still want windows as my main one. I already have 2 partitions. Say I install windows on the first and ubuntu on the second. I want windows to be launched everytime, is there any ways to actually launch ubuntu while my computer is opened on windows or do I have to change the BIOS order every single time ? Thanks

Comment: If your hardware will support it you might want to think about running Ubuntu as a virtual machine.  Here's a starting place to read about it.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualMachines   This will allow you to always have Windows running and you can quickly shift over to Ubuntu when desired.  After running it for a while you may find that you like Ubuntu better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another option: install virtualbox or vmware and install Ubuntu in there. You can then have both active at the same time.

If you choose a dual boot method you need to install both the same way (so this basically means you need to install them both with UEFI by booting from the BIOS to the installer). After that you can pick the operating system you want from the bootloader so there is no need to pick from the BIOS. But I would nowadays opt for virtualization.